# How to find if list contains multiple predicates Java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to figure out how to do multiple predicate on a single filter in Java Lambda but not had much luck.

I have a list of Strings

```
List<String> namesList = new ArrayList(){};
namesList.add("John");
namesList.add("Jane");
namesList.add("Smith");
namesList.add("Roger");
```

I have two if statements below in pseudologic that i want to test but not sure how to do it with lambda (i can do it old school method but trying to learn here).

```
if nameslist contains John and Roger
   print "John & Roger"

if nameslist contains Jane and Smith
   print "Jane Smith"
```

Using Java lambda how can i test for both scenarios on the list?

Comment: What do you mean with `filter`? Since it is an `and` condition, it is hard to do it with one `filter` pass...

Comment: That could be the answer then, i was trying to figure out if there was a way to do it in a single filter. Currently i'm using two to achieve the result.

Comment: @Aeseair: the only thing I can think of is a lambda-expression that maintains state, but that's a rather dirty (and error prone) way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
    if (namesList.stream()
            .filter(x -> (x.equals("John") || x.equals(("Roger"))))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .size() == 2) {
        System.out.print("John & Roger");
    }

    if (namesList.stream()
            .filter(x -> (x.equals("Jane") || x.equals(("Smith"))))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
            .size() == 2) {
        System.out.print("Hane Smith");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use streams: Just convert English to code:

```
if (namesList.contains("John") && namesList.contains("Roger"))
    System.out.println("John & Roger");
```

Or

```
if (namesList.containsAll(Arrays.asList("John", "Roger")))
    System.out.println("John & Roger");
```

It's easier to read and will likely perform as well or better than the stream-based approach.

A lambda is not the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for that @Bohemian. This is the way I had it initially but I was told streams would be a lot quicker and lighter. Especially since im using Strings instead of Objects in this example.

Comment: @aeseir in my experience, streams are quite a lot slower for small numbers of elements. Besides, readability trumps performance, especially in this case - I doubt you would notice a difference in performance between the two, so just do what's easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks mate, I wish i could accept multiple answers but most i can give you is a thumbs up (if you were close it would be a beer too)

Answer (score 0):

You could  combine distinct and count:

```
if (namesList.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.equals("John") || s.equals("Roger"))
        .distinct()
        .count() == 2) {
    System.out.print("John & Roger");
}
```